# Adding part of source path to destination path - and more

Tags: windows, powershell

I feel like this one should be easy, but it's giving me a bit of trouble. The goal is to get downloaded wsus updates migrated to a separate drive that can be burned to a disk and moved to a secure environment.

The current process was set up by another guy and I am taking over. He has 2 batch files that run we will call them **first.bat** and **second.bat**

**first.bat** is run that spits out a log of how many new files there are. We'll call it **new.txt** this simply contains the hash file paths for the changes i.e. `C:\folder\sub\1A\HASHFILE.cab`

Then, we copy the file paths in **new.txt** by hand and manually paste them into **second.bat** ... add in an xcopy function and a destination folder in a new drive. i.e. `xcopy C:\folder\sub\1A\HASHFILE.cab E:\eport\**1A**` However, we have to manually add in the hash folder identifier (1A for example) I would like the script to pick it up from the source folder path and add it into the destination to eliminate the potential for human error.

What I am trying to write a shell script to accomplish is this.

1. run **first.bat**
2. export info from **new.txt** and modify to
3. add xcopy parameter to all new files in **new.txt** as well as the destination folder path
4. automate the addition of the hash folder callout (i.e. 1A to the end of the destination folder path. i.e. `E:\export\**1A**`)
5. run **second.bat**

Anyone have any ideas? I would like to wrap all of this up (or a similar function if that's easier, i imagine it might be) into a handy script that will automate this tedious process.

I have tinkered with a few ideas, I get it to spit out the destination path, but it doesn't actually move anything. Here is what I have so far that successfully tags the hash marker at the end of the destination folder, but does nothing else:

```
$source = "C:\temp\test folder\"
$dest = "C:\Temp2\export\"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $source | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $fname = $folder.FullName
    $sourcefolder = $fname.Replace($source,"")
    $newdest = $dest + $sourcefolder
    Write-Output $newdest
}
```

Comment: What is new.log? A typo?

Comment: every fileinfo object will have a `.Directory` property. you can use that to grab the parent dir of the file and then use `Join-Path` to build the full dest dir.

Comment: Doug - ya sorry that was a typo, I corrected it

Comment: Lee - what would that look like? I've never used ```Join-Path``` before